# Primeng dropdown in form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend, primeng

Hey guys i am using primeng 9 dropdown and i am trying to get the value of the dropdown in form. this is the code `<form #f="ngForm"> <div class="p-col-8"> <p-dropdown  id="group" [options]='groupList'  optionLabel="name" formControlName="group" ngModel></p-dropdown> </div> </form> <button  (click)="addPhoneNo(f)" label="Save"></button>`. The `addPhoneNo(data)`

function prints the value of the form by this code `console.log(data.value)` but the problem is there is no value nor even the control (the dropdown) is not there. pls help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There must be issue with your input to the drop down, which is `[options]='groupList`',
I would suggest that you check what values are being passed on to the variable `grouplist` and then accordingly take actions.

If you refer this URL it might help you. Look out for the Getting Started Section
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown

Comment: `this.groupList = [
    {label:'Select City', value:null},
    {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
    {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
    {label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
    {label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}},
    {label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
];`

Comment: this is the input